# Change date in a row based on multiple IF statements

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to automate the date rows based on the input.

if Due Date is null, THEN add 4 business days after last Take Action date 
if Due Date is not null, THEN add 1 business day after due date 
if Due Date is not null AND Take Action = Next Date, THEN add 4 business days after last Take Action date

```
=IFS(
C1="",WORKDAY(A1,4), 
C1<>"",WORKDAY(C1,1),
AND(C1<>"",INDEX(A1)=INDEX(B1)), WORKDAY(A1,4)
)
```

| A1 | B1(formula) | C1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Take action | Next date | Due date |
| 2024-02-19 | 2024-02-23 | 2024-04-01 |

Basically, let's say our next date is 2024-02-23 
On that day when we take action we change Take action column: 2024-02-23 
This should add another 4 business days into B1 column.

Apologies, if it may sound complicated.
The formula works if I throw "hello world" instead of WORKDAY(), so I'm not sure why is this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a recursive reference to B1, whose value you're just about to calculate. The conditions are also ordered incorrectly.

```
=IFS(
  C1="", 
    WORKDAY(A1, 4), 
  AND(C1<>"", A1=WORKDAY(C1,1)), 
    WORKDAY(A1, 4), 
  TRUE, 
    WORKDAY(C1, 1)
)
```

The last condition is equivalent to `C1<>""` which always evaluates to TRUE because of the first condition.